# Hide fields/columns in MS Access when all values match

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Imagine I have 2 Tables imported from Excel. TableA and TableB as follows:

```
               TableA                                    TableB

    ID_PK    Field1      Field2   Field3           ID_PK      Field1      Field2   Field3        
   -------------------------------------           --------------------------------------
     AA1     Value1      Data1    Reg1              AA1       Value1      Data1     Reg1
     AA2     Value2      Data2    Reg2              AA2       Value2      Data5     Reg2
     AA3     Value3      Data3    Reg3              AA3       Value3      Data3     Reg6
```

Note that there is an "update" for the ID AA2. Previously in Field2 it was Data2 and now in the TableB it is Data5.

First of all I want to show only the row that has changed. I created this query and it works:

```
SELECT TableB.*
FROM TableB 
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.ID_PK = TableA.ID_PK
WHERE 
StrComp([TableB].[Field2],[TableA].[Field2]) Is Null Or
StrComp([TableB].[Field2],[TableA].[Field2])<>0;
```

I get this:

```
                TableA

    ID_PK      Field1      Field2      Field3
   -------------------------------------------
     AA2       Value2      Data2        Reg2
     AA3       Value3      Data3        Reg3
```

My problem now is that I would like to HIDE the column that has not change. 
So, the ouptut would be like this:

```
                TableA

    ID_PK      Field2    Field3
   ------------------------------
     AA2       Data2     Reg2
     AA3       Data3     Reg3
```

I know I can do it manually, but in the case that I have a lot of columns and rows it has to be automatic (maybe with vba code)

The ideal option, but I do not think is posible with MS Access, is to show the full TableB and highlight the cell that has changed.

Any help would be nice!

Thank you!!

Comment: There are no cells in Access. There is only ever a field and the data it contains. You can't treat Access as Excel, they are very different. I don't know of any easy way to dynamically hide a query column based on only it's data being different. What if there were different fields with different data - it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah I know. But maybe is possible with some vba code, comparing with an if statement if both fields (TableA.Field1 and TableB.Field1) are equal, in that case use some hide properties = true. I don't know if it's possible something like that.

Comment: Just imagine that Field1 changes to Value3 for ID AA1 in TableB. What do you expect to be returned? You want column Field1 be hidden because it did not change for the ID AA2. FIeld2 shall be hidden because it did not change for the ID AA1... so both columns should be hidden? You can't dynamically change the design of a query based on the records it returns.

Comment: You can join tables and conditionally display the value in a field with an IIf() expression. But this is not hiding a 'column'. The header label will still display. If you don't want a 'column' to display, don't include the field in the SELECT clause - don't use `*` wildcard to select fields, explicitly reference fields to retrieve. Or build a report and don't bind a textbox to the field.

Comment: The examples you provide are not adequate to show what you want. What happens if you have an `AA3` record where `Field1` has an updated value? What does the result of this look like?

Comment: @WolfgangKais in that case both columns will be returned. Imagine I have a lot of columns, I wanna see the ones that has changed doesn't matter in which row

Comment: @SunKnight0 In the case that I have an AA3 with a Field1 with an updated value, then all the column will show up. If any of the records of that colum has changed then all the column has to be there. This is because I will have a lot of columns and only a few of them will be updated every month and I want to see which ones, even if is just in one register. I know is hard o maybe impossible, I just wanted to ask

Comment: You can't dynamically change the design of a query based on the records it returns.